# Maximum number of Bishops that can be placed on a NxN Chessboard - SPOJ

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, chess

Using the Constant time formula for Maximum bishops on a chessboard, which is:

```
int maxBishops(N) return 2*(N-1);
```

Implemented for the value of N lesser than 10^100, as follows: https://ideone.com/lvuiXW

Verified using Wolfram|Alpha but getting wrong answer on [SPOJ's BISHOPS](http://www.spoj.com/problems/BISHOPS/) submission.

Am I missing something in the algorithm or is it an implementation issue?

Comment: that is the The numbers of rotationally and reflectively distinct solutions,
"The answer is 2n-2", is written there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long sequence of all '0' will make your program fail.

Maybe you should also check for inputs not being a number.

EDIT:
The input case 500000000000001 seems to fail also.
I guess it will just print the carry.